# How do I force Graph Editor to show drivers for my Materials

Tags: drivers

I've rigged this face, adding drivers to shape key values and particle systems. So far so good, but when I add drivers to some node values they don't show up in the Grap Editor when viewing Drivers.

If I create an new empty scene and try to reproduce the issue, it's working as suspected. The material show up beneath the object, and I can expand all the driven inputs.

It's just not working in my previous scene with the face :(

Comment: Related: [is there a caveat to using drivers on node properties?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5357/599)

Comment: There is a cursor icon in the graph editor header that enables only show selected objects, which means the driven node needs to be selected to see the driver.

Comment: I know, I had the mesh selected and saw my other drivers like shape key animations and particle values. Just material or node values that had drivers did not want to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I was stuck there, but removing the drivers back and forth, and adding them not on the node but on the N-panel value forced the Graph Editor to update and I could see the drivers there.